# What is the expression that will always be true while using SQL WHERE IN comparison query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT *  
FROM TABLE_X  
WHERE 'Value' IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE_Y)
```

What expression can I use instead of 'Value' so that the WHERE clause will always return true?

I am trying to do something like:

```
WHERE (SELECT field FROM TABLE_Y) LIKE '%Value%'
```

Comment: Is your RDBMS mysql or sql server?

Comment: Why not just remove the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: If you need to return true always then use 1 = 1 or no where clause at all. But comparing `value` with `Table_Y`, I think you should explain your requirement more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, use `EXISTS` instead of `WHERE IN`:

```
SELECT *  
FROM TABLE_X   
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT field FROM TABLE_Y WHERE field LIKE '%Value%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood it well, it's silly to do the following, but returns all the records in TABLE_X:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_X 
WHERE 1 IN (SELECT field FROM TABLE_Y)
```

NOTE: `...IN (SELECT * ...)` crashes because you should choose just one column, that's why I wrote `field` instead of `*`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare your 'Value' with *, you need a specified field from TABLE_Y, for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_X
WHERE (SELECT Field FROM TABLE_Y WHERE Field LIKE '%Value%' LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL
```